# how to remove background in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools, background-removal

I have a logo on a cream background that I need to delete the cream from so I can make it match the documentit will go on.  In photoshop I would just use the magic wand tool, but I need to know how to do this in illustrator so I can keep it a vector image.

Comment: So many duplicates here regarding this... http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/70404/how-do-i-make-an-object-fill-transparent-without-showing-objects-below-in-illust -- http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7212/how-do-i-delete-the-center-of-the-letter-a-in-adobe-illustrator-cs5 -- http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/69890/how-to-make-two-white-paths-and-a-white-fill-transparent-over-a-black-image-in-i -- http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/70404/how-do-i-make-an-object-fill-transparent-without-showing-objects-below-in-illust

Answer (score 0):

Find the cream layer in your Layers Palette and delete it

In this example, I just threw some random shapes onto my Artboard and placed a colored rectangle behind them all to simulate your cream background

[image]

Select and delete the background layer and you'll have a transparent background

[image]